# Regular Expressions :JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
$(this).val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');  

a = a.replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');  

a = a.replace(/[^\w-]/g, '-');  

a = a.replace(/--+/g, '-');
```

What these statements exactly do ??

I am not getting what these are doing even read about regular expressions,can any one explain me in detail....

Answer (score 0):

- `/^\s+|\s+$/g`: matches whitespace at the beginning or end of a string (replaces with empty string)
- `/^-+|-+$/g`: matches hyphens at the beginning or end of a string (replaces with empty string)
- `/[^\w-]/g`: matches alphanumeric, `_`, and `-` characters (and replaces with a `-`)
- `/--+/g`: matches 2+ `-` in a row (and replaces with a single `-`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation for each of the terms:

> `$(this).val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');`

This replaces any leading spaces or trailing spaces with blanks:

```
"    Hello" -> "Hello"
"Hello    " -> "Hello"
"  Hello  " -> "Hello"
```

---

> `a = a.replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');`

This replaces any leading `-` (1 or more times) or trailing `-` (1 or more times) with blanks.

```
"Hello----" -> "Hello"
"--- Hello ---" -> " Hello "
"-H-E-L-L-O-" -> "H-E-L-L-O"
```

---

> `a = a.replace(/[^\w-]/g, '-');`

This replaces any character that is not (^) a *word character* (in JavaScript, it is defined to include lowercase and uppercase English alphabets, digits 0 to 9 and underscores), or not a '-' with '-'.

```
"    Hello" -> "----Hello"
"Hello@@@@" -> "Hello----"
"Hello--123___" -> "Hello--123___"
"@£"$%"!$" -> ""
```

---

> `a = a.replace(/--+/g, '-');`

This replaces 2 or more consecutive `-` with a single '-'.

```
"--" -> "-"
"Hello--" -> "Hello-"
"------Hello---------" -> "-Hello-"
"H--ello---------" -> "H-ello-"
```

Comment: The last one is wrong. It replaces consecutive `-` with single `-`. And the 3rd one is also wrong, `\w` doesn't allow spaces. The 2nd one "-H-E-L-L-O-" example is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for spotting it, I've corrected it now

Comment: Please run the examples through the console next time. There are still errors after you edited your post, so I edit to correct them.